# How can I control four 12vdc motors?

Tags: switches, dc-motor, motor-controller

I have four of these motors (scroll down to see specs): https://www.aliexpress.us/item/3256801634996956.html?

I want to be able to turn on one motor - then, two - then, three - then, four, running simultaneously as they are turned on thereby increasing the air output through the air-diffuser tube creating air bubbles in the water, similar to an aquarium air pump but with four air pumps in lieu of one. And, this process would also occur in reverse until all motors are turned off again. Essentially, there would be four speeds via turning on/off motors. Hence, all motors would stay at a constant 12V.

How can I accomplish this?

Note: The motors will be powered by from 120VAC to 12VDC power brick with sufficient amperage to run all four motors simultaneously.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did find this video but in my untrained mind, it seems just hooking up to a switch, if it's available, would be less expensive and more simple: 
https://youtu.be/dyjo_ggEtVU

Comment: Would this switch work? 

https://a.co/d/ciP7nLD

What's confusing me is...I always thought a changeover switch would turn off the position prior to the current position. Possibly it's all in how I hook it up? I know I need five positions: Off, 1, 2, 3, 4. So, on the surface this looks like this might could work but I know just enough to be VERY dangerous :)

Comment: The stuff in the video is not what you need. If you don't mind using a BIG switch why not 4 smaller switches?

Comment: @Rodo That's one way to do it. However, I prefer one larger switch because this is a prototype that may go to market and installing one larger switch is easier than four smaller switches. Also, if I used four switches, they would need to be push button and not toggle. This is on a small health and beauty product and the user's right hand would need to be able to easily change the switch (speed). Hence, the ideal setup (I think) for manufacturing and ease of use would be to turn a knob via one switch. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I posted my question on Amazon as to whether or not that large switch in the link above would work. A person (not the seller) answered that it would work for my intended purpose. However, when I Google "Can I use an AC switch on DC motors?" the majority of the posts indicate that you can't use an AC switch on DC motors. Hmmm?

Comment: The fourth image on the Baomain cam switch you've shown indicates that only one set of contacts is closed in each position, unlike what you're after where each successive position closes an extra pair of contacts. I forget if there is a term for what you're after; it is certainly acheivable but less common.

Comment: As for AC vs DC, while switches generally must be significantly derated for DC use, you are intending to use them at 12V DC instead of the typical 240V or higher AC. This is entirely adequate and likely supported by the documentation in the fine print.

Comment: Alternative suggestion: have you considered one large fan/motor and a speed controller?

Comment: Schneider has a [cam switch configurator](https://www.se.com/ww/confsdl/camswitchconfig/configuration), and you could [send the results](https://www.se.com/ww/confsdl/camswitchconfig/download/pdf/K2SD700182) to practically any manufacturer. It doesn't look like the config you want is directly off the shelf but cam switches are *very* flexible in what they can do.

Comment: Wow, thanks for all the research and suggestions @SomeoneSomewhereSupportsMonica
I am digesting all that you have said and will continue my research. Once I find an answer, I'll report back. Thanks again!!!

Comment: "Alternative suggestion: have you considered one large fan/motor and a speed controller?" Yes, it won't fit in the small container. I actually found a micro piston pump which is much better than a diaphragm pump but at 4.5" long x 3.5" tall x 1.5" wide it was too big for the compartment.

Comment: @tayglo What pressure & flow are you looking for?

Comment: We tested a mini air piston pump and it worked great but it was slightly too large to fit into our compartment.  Here are the specs off of that pump - we probably have some play to venture away from these numbers a bit. 
Working voltage: DC9V-14V
Pressure: 300kpa
Nominal flow: 20L/min
Rated voltage: 12V
Power: 17W

Comment: Also, all the diaphragm pumps we tested for longevity have since failed which voids my prior idea in this post about using four small diaphragm pumps. So it looks like, we are down to mini piston pumps and if I can't find one small enough to fit, we will need to increase the size of the compartment.

Comment: these types of mini piston pumps run forever. But just a little too big:

https://www.aliexpress.us/item/2251832839362109.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem has been solved. Because diaphragm pumps have a short life span compared to piston pumps, we decided to go with one larger piston pump and use a PWM controller for variable speed. Thanks